# Google Play Games initialization crash on certain devices - Start Service Action failure

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've been seeing the following issue crop up fairly often in the Google Play Developer console for one of my apps. It seems to be happening most often on Android 9 and mostly on Samsung Galaxy devices but I'm unable to reproduce on any of my own devices.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Class name: zzf. Start service action: com.google.android.gms.games.service.START. Service Descriptor: com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IGamesService. 
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$a.a(Unknown Source:20)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzc.c(Unknown Source:11)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$b.handleMessage(Unknown Source:49)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zze.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:8)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

I've already ensured that I've got the following `meta-data` tags under my `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud saves have a chance to throw IllegalStateExceptions. Is it possible that you're calling getData in case of a conflict where getConflict should be called instead?

ref: 
[SnapshotsClient.DataOrConflict](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/SnapshotsClient.DataOrConflict)